# No funciona maquina tragamonedas Jquery y Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estoy programando una maquina traga.monedas con javascript y jquery, soy incapaz de encontrar por que las imagenes del tragamonedas no se actualizan...A continuacion les explico el codigo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MaquinaTragamonedas</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="JQuery-clase/Js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script> <!--Referenciando la hoja con el framework-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> <!--Referenciando el cdn -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Especifico las carpetas de jquery

```
    <style>
        .l1 {
            background-size: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .l2 {
            background-size: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .l3 {
            background-size: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
    </style>
```

Creo 3 clases las cuales cada una hace referencia a cada espacio que ocupa cada imagen en la maquina tragamonedas

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnaccionar").on('click',function(){
        funciones();  
    });

   function NroRandom1() 
    {
      var N1 = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
      if(N1==0)
        {
            N1=N1+1;
        } 
        else
            {
                N1=N1;
            }
        if(N1==1)
        {
                $(".l1").attr("src","Img/img1.jpg");  
                $(".l1").attr("alt","ran1-img1");
        }
    else
        {
            if(N1==2)
                {
                        $(".l1").attr("src","Img/img2.jpg");
                        $(".l1").attr("alt","ran1-img2");
                }
            else
                {
                        $(".l1").attr("src","Img/img3.PNG");  
                        $(".l1").attr("alt","ran1-img3");
                }
        }
    }
    function NroRandom2() 
    {
      var N2 = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
      if(N2==0)
        {
            N2=N2+1;
        }  
        else
            {
                N2=N2;
            }
        if(N2==1)
        {
                $(".l2").attr("src","Img/img1.jpg"); 
                $(".l2").attr("alt","ran2-img1");
        }
    else
        {
            if(N2==2)
                {
                        $(".l2").attr("src","Img/img2.jpg");
                        $(".l2").attr("alt","ran2-img2");
                }
            else
                {
                        $(".l2").attr("src","Img/img3.PNG"); 
                        $(".l2").attr("alt","ran2-img3");
                }

        }
    }
    function NroRandom3() 
    {
      var N3 = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
      if(N3==0)
        {
            N3=N3+1;
        } 
        else
            {
                N3=N3;
            }

         if(N3==1)
        {
                $(".l3").attr("src","Img/img1.jpg"); 
                $(".l3").attr("alt","ran3-img1");
        }
    else
        {
            if(N3==2)
                {
                        $(".l3").attr("src","Img/img2.jpg"); 
                        $(".l3").attr("alt","ran3-img2");
                }
            else
                {
                        $(".l3").attr("src","Img/img3.PNG");  
                        $(".l3").attr("alt","ran3-img3");
                }
        }
    } 
    function funciones()
    {
        NroRandom1();
        NroRandom2();
        NroRandom3();
    }
}
</script>
```

Hago una funcion que llama las 3 funciones anteriores para hacer funcionar la maquina tragamonedas

```
</head>
<body>

<table align="center" class="table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><img id="l1" class="l1" src="Img/img1.jpg"></th>
        <th><img id="l2" class="l2" src="Img/img2.jpg"></th> 
        <th><img id="l3" class="l3" src="Img/img3.png"></th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Hago una tabla que tiene 3 th, en cada uno una imagen que tiene asignada una clase, para asì poder cambiar la imagen (Por jquery) segun la clase

```
<td style="text-align:left">
<button id="btnaccionar" class="btn-lg">Usar</button>
</td>
```

Genero un boton que al ser presionado deberia llamar las funciones y hacer funcionar la maquina, pero nada cambia

```
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo utilizando tu codigo pero con unos cambios.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


$("#btnaccionar").on('click',function(){
Funciones();

});
    
    function NroRandom1() 
    {
      var N1 = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
      if(N1==0)
        {
            N1=N1+1;
        } 
        else
            {
                N1=N1;
            }
        if(N1==1)
        {
          
                $(".l1").attr("src","https://www.artescritorio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/monsterball-portada.png"); 
 $(".l1").attr("alt","ran1-img1"); 

        }
    else
        {
            if(N1==2)
                {
                    
                        $(".l1").attr("src","http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/128/Perspective-Button-Standby-icon.png"); 
                        $(".l1").attr("alt","ran1-img2"); 
                      
                }
            else
                {
                        $(".l1").attr("src","https://norfipc.com/img/logos/icono-android.png"); 
                        $(".l1").attr("alt","ran1-img3"); 
                }
        }
    }
    function NroRandom2() 
    {
      var N2 = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
      if(N2==0)
        {
            N2=N2+1;
        }  
        else
            {
                N2=N2;
            }
        if(N2==1)
        {
                $(".l2").attr("src","https://www.artescritorio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/monsterball-portada.png");  
$(".l2").attr("alt","ran2-img1");  
        }
    else
        {
            if(N2==2)
                {
                        $(".l2").attr("src","http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/128/Perspective-Button-Standby-icon.png"); 
$(".l2").attr("alt","ran2-img2"); 
                }
            else
                {
                        $(".l2").attr("src","https://norfipc.com/img/logos/icono-android.png");  
$(".l2").attr("alt","ran2-img3");  
                }
        }
    }
    function NroRandom3() 
    {
      var N3 = Math.round(Math.random()*3);
      if(N3==0)
        {
            N3=N3+1;
        } 
        else
            {
                N3=N3;
            }

         if(N3==1)
        {
               $(".l3").attr("src","https://www.artescritorio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/monsterball-portada.png"); 
$(".l3").attr("alt","ran3-img1");                
        }
    else
        {
            if(N3==2)
                {
                        $(".l3").attr("src","http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/128/Perspective-Button-Standby-icon.png"); 
$(".l3").attr("alt","img2"); 
                }
            else
                {
$(".l3").attr("src","https://norfipc.com/img/logos/icono-android.png"); 
$(".l3").attr("alt","ran3-img3"); 
                }
        }
    }
    
    function Funciones()
    {
        NroRandom1();
        NroRandom2();
        NroRandom3();
    }
    
});
```

```css
 .l1 {
            background-size: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .l2 {
            background-size: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .l3 {
            background-size: 40px;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" class="table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><img id="l1" class="l1" src="https://www.artescritorio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/monsterball-portada.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></th>
        <th><img id="l2" class="l2" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mazenl77/I-like-buttons-3a/128/Perspective-Button-Standby-icon.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></th> 
        <th><img id="l3" class="l3" src="https://norfipc.com/img/logos/icono-android.png" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></th>
      </tr>
</table>

<td style="text-align:left">
<button id="btnaccionar" class="btn-lg">Usar</button>
</td>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: puedes poner tu ejemplo con el sniper al formular tu respuesta

Comment: @x-rw editado gracias.

Comment: @DMG Gracias,hice las correcciones que propones pero sigue sin funcionarme, te pregunto que hace  $(".l1").attr("alt","ran1-img3"); y sobre todo que es "ran1-img3"

Comment: @Gammath.rar solo es el texto que aparece cuando no carga o no encuentra la imagen no deberian afectar, lo use para probar el codigo sin imagenes ran1-img3 solo hace referencia a que esta dentro del  random 1 - imagen 3, que es lo que no te funciona o te marca error?.

Comment: @DMG No, solo que era lo unico que no me cuadraba en los cambios y como es algo que desconocía pensé que era la razon de que siguiera sin funcionar, no funciona, simplemente se queda en las imagenes con las que comienza y al usar el boton nada pasa, actualicé la pregunta por si me puedes ayudar
PD: Uso Brackets (No sé si afecte en algo)

Comment: @Gammath.rar veo que al final de tu script tienes                                        }
</script>    deberias tener });
</script>

Comment: @DMG muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, ese era el problema...Uno siempre se termina fijando en el {} y ; pero nunca el ()